# Arriving in terminal 2 going to 5 heathrow

Tags: transit, lhr, shopping

If I follow flight connections can I get to the terminal 2 shops before transferring by shuttle bus to terminal 5

Comment: Almost all the shops can be found in all the terminals, so for most things you should be fine to shop at T5.

Comment: @Gagravarr not true, there are different shops in each terminal (for example Chanel is in terminal 3 and 5 while Louis Vuitton is only in terminal 5) hence why they have the personal shopping service.  The OP is likely asking because they have found something specific

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 I stand by what I said - almost all the shops are in all the terminals. Not every single one, and you've found some of the only examples, but for almost all the shopping someone might (sensibly) want to do in Heathrow, it can be done in all terminals. The OP hasn't mentioned something specific, so there's a fair chance they just haven't realised they could do it in T5 (which is what Heathrow normally want you to do)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if the "normal" flow you allow you to do this, but note the following items from the [Heathrow shopping FAQ](http://boutique.heathrow.com/faqs):

> **Can items be transferred between terminals?**
>
> If a product you would like to purchase is available at any terminal
>   in Heathrow, we can arrange to have the product transferred to the
>   terminal you are flying from, provided that the brand has a shop in
>   your departure terminal so you can make the payment. Some brands offer
>   a telephone payment service, in which case they can accept pre-payment
>   and we can meet you with your purchase. Please enquire about this with
>   our Shopping Services team.
>
> **Can I shop in other terminals not just the one I am departing from?**
>
> If you have enough time before your flight, it is possible to be
>   transferred to another terminal to visit stores that are not available
>   at the terminal you are flying from. To do this, an escorted transfer
>   needs to be arranged in advance, which can be requested using our
>   Terminal Shopping Transfer form.
>
> Because of the staff costs involved in offering this service, we do
>   ask that passengers commit to make purchases of £250 or more when
>   using the service.
>
> **If I am being escorted to another terminal to shop, how soon must I arrive prior to my departure?**
>
> We recommend 3 - 3 1/2 hours before your departure time to complete
>   the transfer process and allow you time to make your purchase.

Your best bet is probably to [contact the Heathrow Shopping services team](http://boutique.heathrow.com/contact-us) or the specific store you would like to buy from, they should be able to assist.

Comment: You let them know your flight number flying in (if appropriate) and flight number flying out.  They will arrange a personal assistant who will follow you around while you shop (the entire time) and escort you between terminals.  If you shop long enough they will take you to a "rest" area and offer you free tea and coffee.